# Interapt current action and chang activity

Tags: android

I want to consider follow example.

```
 btnRegistr.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {

            int x= 0;
            while(1==1){
                x++;
        }
        });

   btnTest.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

       public void onClick(View v) {

        Intent browserIntent = new Intent("android.intent.action.VIEW", Uri.parse("http://www.google.com"));
            startActivity(browserIntent);

        }
        });
}
```

When I am clicking btnRegistr started infinite cycle.
After that I want   when I am clicking Test button,interapt the cycle and go to another activity.
Is it possible??
Like this,in my application when user attemting get some data from remote server and in that time he click another button for some action(change activity for exmp),I want to stop that process and follow new command of user.
And another problem,when I am clicking back button the activity does not changed ,but I have read that current acivity is distroyed and started previous activity.
Thanks.

Comment: As a side note: Consider accepting answers on questions you have posed. You can do this by clicking on the checkmark next to the question.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible via UI button, as your infinite loop blocks the UI thread so that it does not return to the OS.

When you consider the real world use case of downloading a file, you usually put the download in a background task (e.g. via `AsyncTask`) that may be cancellable.

Comment: but how works back button?? It's works in same thread???If yes,I think this not clever,because  possible situation when within application occures infinite loop  cases.

Comment: BackButton creates a "hardware interrupt", which is treated at much deeper OS levels.

Comment: can you write me some links how implemented back action??

Comment: Have a look at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onBackPressed()